# How should the charge carrier concentration be examined in the quantum Hall effect?

Tags: quantum-hall-effect

In the classical Hall effect, the charge carrier concentration is given by $n = \frac{1}{e R_{H}}$, where $e$ is the electron charge and $R_{H}$ the Hall coefficient, which is obtained from the slope of the curve representing the Hall resistance against the magnetic field, right?

In the quantum Hall effect, on the other hand, we have resistance plateaus, which are connected by linear segments. So my question is, do each of these segments have a Hall coefficient associated with them? If this is the case, since the slopes are not equal, does it mean that each section has a different charge carrier concentration associated with it?

Also, how does one obtain the charge concentration at the plateaus? I have seen the formula

$B = \frac{n}{\nu}\Phi_{0}$

where $B$ is the magnetic field at the center of a plateau, $\Phi_{0}$ is the flux quantum and $\nu$ is the filling factor associated with each plateau. This equation is, however, obtained from

$\nu = R_{K}/R_{xy}$,

being $R_{K}$ is the resistance quantum and $R_{xy}$ is the Hall resistance, and from

$R_{H} = \frac{R_{xy}}{B}$,

but the Hall coefficient is not well defined at the plateaus as the Hall resistance is zero for sufficiently large magnetic fields.

Thank you very much.